# How to create a Template for a ViewModel and View?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, mvvm

I was wondering if it is possible to create a template for a view model and view.

I would like to add a common structure to both, so when i add the new `ViewModel` or `View` it will all ready have all my common regions, fields, constructors, properties and methods.

So when i add the new `ViewModel` or `View` it will all ready have all the code i need to create it.

Note: I am not talking about `ViewModelBase` or `ViewBase`. I have that in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the [codeplex toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Model-View-ViewModel%20Toolkit) before, which I found pretty useful:

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get you correctly, but have a look at [Visual Studio Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
If you need examples for templates have a look at [MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) it contains several templates for custom classes and views.

Another possibility (or rather a poor mans version) for a template would be a codesnippet.